# What's the difference between static interface with usual interface without such keyword in java?

Tags: java, interface, dictionary, static

I wonder what's the  difference between **static interface** with usual interface without such keyword in java?
And When and where we should use the **static** keyword before **interface**.And why we should use it ? You can take this interface as an example 
Thank you so much!

 `public static interface Map.Entry<K,V>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no difference: `static` is *implied* - all interfaces are effectively static.

The use or not or the `static` keyword is a matter of style. Personally, I prefer to use `static` as it's in keeping with the semantics of an inner static *class*.

Comment: I prefer to use it too. Likewise with inner `enum` declarations, just so it doesn't confuse people that don't know this caveat, like how you can declare interface methods without an access modifier since they're inherently `public`. +1

Answer (score 0):

interfaces are inherently static.
You cannot declare an interface inside a block. For example, the following code excerpt **does not compile** because the interface HelloThere is defined inside the body of the method greetInEnglish:

```
public void greetInEnglish() {
    interface HelloThere {
       public void greet();
    }
    class EnglishHelloThere implements HelloThere {
        public void greet() {
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        }
    }
    HelloThere myGreeting = new EnglishHelloThere();
    myGreeting.greet();
}
```